# Difference in starting pronunciations of "station" and "sun"

Tags: pronunciation

Why do some English speakers have different starting pronunciations of *station* and *sun*? *Station* is pronounced as *e-station* while *sun* simply as *sun*. Is the difference due to the fact that the second letter is a vowel in *sun* but not in *station*?

Comment: I think this question is not for down vote

Comment: But *station* and *sun* **do** both start with the same letter *s* sound.

Comment: Could you provide a more clear example?

Comment: @andrew IMHO: sound is different that is station starts with "e-station" and sun sounds as "sun" simply.

Comment: I would like to know where you get the impression that _station_ starts with an "e-" sound when vocalized. I've never heard it that way; moreover, my dictionary's pronunciation guides don't show any vowel sound at the beginning of the word.

Comment: @RTA - This is an excellent question; but it sounds like a regionalism to me.  Are the people who insert a vowel at the start of "station" native speakers of English?  If not, you could probably ignore the difference.

Comment: @David I really could not understand why i am getting down vote but feeling good as you admire it. it have certainly difference in sound that i want to raise out.

Comment: @Jasper yes i got it.

Comment: @Jasper o no you are not understanding it. I think David have got it. i just mean with station and sun that they have difference in sound pronunciation for letter 's'. is it such hard to understand what i want to say?

Comment: RTA: It's not "hard to understand," but it's very puzzling. For one, I've never heard the first part of the word _station_ pronounced any differently than the "s" in _sun_.  For example, listen to the first few seconds of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Eq8g-M1Sy8): where is the "e-"? Secondly, what do you mean by the "E-" sound? Is that the long "e" (as in "bee") or the short "e" (as in "pet")? Note: I wanted to get a clip of "we now pause for station identification," (which I've heard all my life) but I couldn't find one!

Comment: forget the 'e'. is their any difference in {school,stand,station} in compare of {sunday,sun, sound} in term of sound of pronunciation?

Comment: No. there is NO difference in the S-sound of any of those words. In "Spanish" they seem to prohibit Starting Syllables 'S'. The say "es-" before it instead. So Spanish speaking people would perhaps say something that sounded like es-station. They think the name "Scott" is very funny when I say it! They say something that sounds like "Es-Gott".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you look up the official pronunciation of 'sun' and 'station' you get respectively

- sun - /sʌn/
- station - /ˈsteɪʃən/

with no notated difference. No standard or dialectal variety of English has any difference either.

But it is the case in many foreign languages that they do not allow the complicated consonant cluster of /s/ followed by a harder consonant, or some change is needed to the /s/. Then this gives a sound change when they try to speak English.

This is especially true of Spanish where there are many close cognate words or borrowings from the same source (Latin). For example:

> school (En) - escuela (Sp)

This is a pattern for 's' followed by 't', 'p', or 'k'. There is a tendency for native Spanish speakers to naturally say the English word 'school' as 'ehs-kool', which is closer to their own native pronunciation.

In Japanese, because any consonant pair is forbidden, they tend to put a vowel -between- an English word that has two consonants 'suh- koo -luh' (and a vowel at the end.

So I suspect that the 'estation' pronunciation that you are hearing is from a non-native speaker of English that speaks a native lanaguage that treats 'st' differently than English. No native variety of English has a difference between 'sun' and 'station' for 's'.

The 't' in 'station' is a whole nother story.

Comment: The [Brazilians are also wont](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_phonology#Epenthesis) to insert epenthetic `/i/` into spoken words, and they do so in places where a Portuguese person (=from Portugal) or a Spaniard would not feel any need to. For example, say they don’t like a *dv* cluster, so in goes an *i* (which now also triggers palatalization), and the word *adverso* may come out `/adʒiˈvɛχsu/` for them. This somewhat reminds me of Japanese in this regard.

Comment: I've heard a similar tendency from my Korean friends, who tend to add an extra vowel sound at end of words with complex blends (particularly when they ask me to go to "lunchie"). (That was the first thing I thought of when I read the O.P.'s question, but I couldn't put 2 and 2 together. Thanks for the explanation.)

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question, instead of denying its thesis.

Comment: @Mitch you have mentioned three letters 't','p','k' only these three, but i think many word like 'scam' which is followed by 'c' is also the similar case.

Comment: @RTA: in English, 'c' after 's' is either silent or the same sound as 'k', so you wouldn't consider that a new case. Those three, p, t, k, are the only 'unvoiced stops' in English.

Comment: @Mitch good one , +10 for capturing the right nerves of question while i was getting a lots of down vote in the beginning.

Comment: In Ireland, it's common to stick a vowel between some consonants that would require that in Irish, even among people who haven't had a native Irish speaker in their ancestry for several generations. Hence some don't even realise why they say *film* with two syllables, or that it's not pronounced that way elsewhere.

Comment: And of course, English speakers do the opposite when they borrow words from Greek, knocking off part of words that begin with *X* or *PT*.

Comment: So, how do Spanish speakers say 'sun'? es-sun?

Comment: @user126158 There is no consonant cluster, so "sun" is unproblematic for Spanish speakers.  It's when the *s* is followed by another (plosive) consonant.

Comment: You have the same tendency in Italian and perhaps French as well.

Answer (score 16):

The only people who pronounce *station* (or *scale* or *school*) with a leading *e* sound before the *s* are those who cannot pronounce a “liquid s”; that is, native Spanish speakers.

Which is why they say *estación* ( and *escala* and *escuela*), at least when speaking Spanish.

Because of this, sometimes when native Spanish (or Portuguese) speakers speak English, they introduce an [**epenthetic *e***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthetic_vowel#At_the_beginning_of_a_word) at the front of words beginning with an *s* that is followed by a consonant.  They do this so they can split up the consonant cluster, placing the *s* at the end of a new first syllable, and the other consonant at the start of the next one.

They also do this [when borrowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthetic_vowel#When_borrowing_words) English words into Spanish.  So English  *stress* becomes Spanish *estrés*, just as English *standard* becomes Spanish *estándar*.  Notice they drop the *d* at the end, because they can’t say an *rd* at the end.  They can’t say most consonants at the end of a syllable, actually. That’s why when they say the borrowed word *stop*, this comes out sounding like *estó*, *estod* (IPA `/esˈtoð/`), or *estoz* (IPA `/esˈtoθ/`)  — and  sometimes even *estof*.  Since they can’t have a final *p* either, they have to substitute in something that works for them.

It may be that native speakers of other languages also introduce an epenthetic *s* at the front of English *station*.  However, this is not a standard pronunciation, and would mark you for a non-native speaker.

Comment: Jinx! (same answer at same time)

Comment: I was very confused when I first heard this question, but now I understand. Great answer. I'm ecstatic that you cleared the _estatic_.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question, instead of denying its thesis.

Comment: +1 You might find it interesting that a lot of people in parts of India introduce an epenthetic _i_ at the beginning of words like _school_, _skin_ and _space_ (ɪskuːl, ɪskɪn, ɪspeɪs). This happens although many native Indian languages have words starting with the _s_  sound followed by a consonant sound (they pronounce the epenthetic _i_ in their native languages as well). For me to understand this phenomenon, I suppose I will have to delve into the origins of native Indian languages.

Comment: I think I might find that Indian languages spoken by the "common people" either didn't have such sounds originally or had the _i_ sound at the beginning of such words, and that words with these sounds were introduced by the intelligentsia or ruling elite (just guesswork at this point).

Comment: @Tragicomic Quite likely it happened the same way as in Spanish (and Portuguese, Catalan, French, etc.—basically all the West Romance areas): the words started out having /sC/, and then at some point, the community of speakers collectively decided that that was too much of a bother to pronounce, so they started adding prop vowels. (I believe Turkish also tends to add /i-/, while Finnish does the opposite and drops as many consonants as needed; the Swedish loan words _strand_ and _president_, for instance, become _ranta_ and _residentti_, though the latter mostly _presidentti_ nowadays.)

Answer (score 5):

*Station* doesn't begin with an “e” sound, it starts with an “s” sound, just like *sun*.

Here's how the *Oxford English Dictionary* says they should be pronounced:

> ### `/ˈsteɪʃən/`
>
> **st** - ay - sh - ə - n 
>    IPA      Sounds like
>
> - `st`            st        as in **st**ay, po**st** (main stress)
> - `eɪ`            ay        as in b**ay**
> - `ʃ`     sh        as in **sh**op, di**sh**
> - `ə`     ə         as in **a**noth**e**r (schwa)
> - `n`     n         as in **n**ine
>
> ### `/sʌn/`
>
> s - u - n
>
> IPA          Sounds like
>
> - `s`            s         as in **s**ee
> - `ʌ`            u         as in b**u**tter, **u**pset
> - `n`            n         as in **n**ine

Although note the `ˈ` mark in `/ˈsteɪʃən/` and not in `/sʌn/`. This symbol is placed before the stressed syllable.