# What about adjective "especial" for a person?

Tags: compound-adjectives

I read about the use of especial and special. But I'm not sure if applies the same when describing a person.

For instance, do you say:

> I am an **especial** person.

or

> I am a **special** person.

Comment: Especial is not used very often. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=especial%2C+special&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cespecial%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cspecial%3B%2Cc0

Comment: *What* did you read about the two, and where?

Comment: As @sooeithdk said, *especial* exists in English, but it is used rarely. More commonly it is used in English by native Spanish speakers, either as a "false friend" (similar word) or simply through mispronunciation of *special*.

Comment: Virtually the only (non-erroneous) use of "especial" in English is in the adverb form -- "especially".  Since it is so rare it's misuse will stick out like an especially sore thumb, so it's best avoided until you're fairly familiar with it's use.

Comment: What @Drew said - as covered by [Difference in starting pronunciations of “station” and “sun”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71137/difference-in-starting-pronunciations-of-station-and-sun)

Answer (score 1):

You would never say, "I am an especial person".  *Especial* is seldom used as an adjective, almost always as an adverb:

> He is a special person, especially when it comes to helping others.